# How to move files one by one using java

Tags: java, scheduler

i know how to send all files from one directory to another in one time.
but how can i want send files (.txt) from one directory to another one by one with a delay of 60s.

```
import java.io.File;

public class MoveFilesJavaExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File oldFile = new File("C:\\source\\File.txt");

            if (oldFile.renameTo(new File("C:\\destination"+ oldFile.getName()))) {
                System.out.println("The file was moved successfully to the new folder");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The File was not moved.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can use the following code but it only do the same job every 5s.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class UtilTimerDemo {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
    int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("doing"); 
      }
    }, delay, period);
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand. You know how to move a single file, and you know how to schedule a task. Why not combine both?

Comment: If you want a delay of sixty seconds, why are you specifying a delay of one second?

Comment: But it move all files in one time, i want to move files one by one

Comment: when you call renameTo, you are only moving 1 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inside your TimerTask, use `File#listFiles()` (possibly with the `FilenameFilter` parameter, if that suits your needs) to get a list of files in the source directory.
2. Iterate through the returned Files looking for the first item that is not a directory (assuming that you want to move only normal files).
3. Move that file.
4. Optionally (depending on your requirements) if you got to the end of the array of returned Files and didn't find any non-directories, then stop the TimerTask.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start a `Timer` that fires every 60 seconds.
2. In the constructor of the `Timer`, use [`DirectoryStream<Path>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream) to get all the files in a directory. This is done using the static method of `Files` class in the `nio` package.
3. Then, use [`Files.move()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move) in the `Timer` to move the files one by one.
4. Stop the `Timer` when you have iterated over all the files in the stream.

`DirectoryStream` can be globbed, thus allowing you to filter the files that you want. You can either write simple extensions or complex RegEx to decide what files are returned in your `DirectoryStream`.